# MYSQL gives this error

Tags: php, mysql

this is the code I'm trying to put in, but it gives this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2.

I cannot figure out what's wrong, any help?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hijstesten;

CREATE TABLE hijstesten (
opdrachtnummer INT NOT NULL,
volgnummer INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
datum_opgesteld DATE NOT NULL,
hoofdgiek_lengte DOUBLE NOT NULL,
mech_sectie_gieklengte DOUBLE NOT NULL,
hulpgiek_lengte DOUBLE NOT NULL,
hoofdgiek_giekhoek DOUBLE NOT NULL,
hulphoek_giekhoek DOUBLE NOT NULL,
hijskabel_aantal_parten INT NOT NULL,
zwenkhoek DOUBLE NOT NULL,
eigen_massa_ballast DOUBLE NOT NULL,
toelaatbare_bedrijflast DOUBLE NOT NULL,
LMB_in_werking DOUBLE NOT NULL,
proeflast DOUBLE NOT NULL,
akkoord BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (volgnummer),
FOREIGN KEY(opdrachtnummer)REFERENCES opdrachten(opdrachtnummer));

INSERT INTO hijstesten (opdrachtnummer, volgnummer, datum_opgesteld, hoofdgiek_lengte, mech_sectie_gieklengte, hulpgiek_lengte, hoofdgiek_giekhoek, hulphoek_giekhoek, hijskabel_aantal_parten, zwenkhoek, eigen_massa_ballast, toelaatbare_bedrijflast, LMB_in_werking, proeflast, akkoord) VALUES (
(1,1,"2017-06-03","30.5","10.2","25.4","30.1°","20.7°","12","12.8","110","1120","1200","1300",TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although i have not worked with MariaDB, i suggest to check
1. If you are writing the query syntactically right.
2. Try to execute queries one by one to find out which query really has the problem.
3. As you are trying to create a foreign key constraint on opdrachtnummer, i am sure you already created a table for that reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra parenthesis at the end of `VALUES`. Use this

```
INSERT INTO hijstesten (opdrachtnummer, volgnummer, datum_opgesteld, hoofdgiek_lengte, mech_sectie_gieklengte, hulpgiek_lengte, hoofdgiek_giekhoek, hulphoek_giekhoek, hijskabel_aantal_parten, zwenkhoek, eigen_massa_ballast, toelaatbare_bedrijflast, LMB_in_werking, proeflast, akkoord)  
VALUES (1,1,"2017-06-03","30.5","10.2","25.4","30.1°","20.7°","12","12.8","110","1120","1200","1300",TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

change INSERT INTO hijstesten (( to INSERT INTO hijstesten (

```
 INSERT INTO hijstesten (opdrachtnummer, volgnummer, datum_opgesteld, hoofdgiek_lengte, mech_sectie_gieklengte, hulpgiek_lengte, hoofdgiek_giekhoek, hulphoek_giekhoek, hijskabel_aantal_parten, zwenkhoek, eigen_massa_ballast, toelaatbare_bedrijflast, LMB_in_werking, proeflast, akkoord) VALUES (1,1,"2017-06-03","30.5","10.2","25.4","30.1°","20.7°","12","12.8","110","1120","1200","1300",TRUE);
```